# Composer fix/override dependency

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

I am new to the whole composer situation.
i am using laravel5.1, and i am trying to upgrade to laravel 5.2
I have updated the composer.json file to reflect as such, i then run

```
composer update
```

I get the following error

```
rappasoft/vault dev-master requires illuminate/support 5.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.1.40], illuminate/support[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
    - rappasoft/vault dev-master requires illuminate/support 5.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.1.40], illuminate/support[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
```

So i understand the package doesn't support laravel 5.2, so i went to the vendor/rappasoft/vault/composer.json file and updated that to say it could support 5.2 but that didn't work.

Whats the best way to move forward? the rappasoft/vault package is no longer supported, but its heavily embedded in the project i am working on, so i will be upgrading it myself.. i just don't know what the best move forward is.

Thoughts?